# For from a range(0, value goal)

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

'Hi, I'm trying to calculate how many months to achieve a million dollars with compounding interest and monthly investments. There are my tries.'

'This first code work, but I want to replace the 92 in the rage with a compare formula like fv >= 1000000.'

'When I place the range like here, it doesn't work.'

Comment: pv = 130000 # present value
i = 4000 # regular monthly investment
r = 0.1375 # annual interest rate
n = 1 # number of months


for n in range(0, 92):
    fv = pv * (1 + r/12)**n + i*(((1 + r/12)**n - 1) / (r/12)) 
    print(fv)
    print(n)

Comment: pv = 130000 # present value
i = 4000 # regular monthly investment
r = 0.1375 # annual interest rate
n = 120 # number of months


for n in range(0, 92):
    fv = pv * (1 + r/12)**n + i*(((1 + r/12)**n - 1) / (r/12)) 
    print(fv)
    print(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try while-loop may help:

```
pv = 130000  # present value
i = 4000  # regular monthly investment
r = 0.1375  # annual interest rate
n = 0  # number of months
# for n in range(0, 92):
fv = 0
while fv < 1000000:
    fv = pv * (1 + r / 12) ** n + i * (((1 + r / 12) ** n - 1) / (r / 12))
    n += 1 #don't forget
    print(fv)
    print(n)
```

You need to manually increase the value of n

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).